# Cluster weights in PROC GLMPOWER

Tags: statistical-power, weighted-data, cluster-sample, weights

I am doing power analyses in SAS using PROC GLMPOWER to solve for a total sample size (N Total). I have clustered data (Ward method), to account for variability. There are 4 clusters of varying sample sizes (16, 38, 6, 6) and they are split evenly between test and control groups, i.e. half of each cluster will be in the test group and half will be in the control group. When running the power analyses, my N total increases greatly (from 32 to 132) when I include weights for the clusters vs when I don't. I find that when I use weights reflecting relative proportion rather than actual sample size, I get different N Totals, which seems incorrect. Is weighting clusters in power analysis necessary when using clustered data? What is the correct weighting method (sample size vs relative)?

Comment: Ward method refers to hierarchical clustering of similar objects. Clustering in GLMPOWER refers to clusters created by design. These are quite different ideas. Are you sure this is your design as described??